# Golang: Recursive function for reconnecting a TCP client... Bad idea?

Tags: go, recursion, tcp

I have this working TCP client code. When it fails to Write or Read on the TCP connection, it creates a new connection with the recursive function tcpReconnect().

**Is this safe or will it fill up the RAM?** It is possible that it may be trying to reconnect over several days (weekend or holidays). This is code is part of a Driver that monitors the state of an industrial Machine.

Maybe there is a better solution for this problem. I was not able to find one.

PS: I don't like polling

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

var pollTime = 1000 //ms
var host = "127.0.0.1"
var port = "11000"

func main() {
    finished := make(chan bool)
    go Driver()
    <-finished
}

func tcpReconnect() net.Conn {
    newConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to reconnect:", err.Error())
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(2000))
        newConn = tcpReconnect()
    }
    return newConn
}

func Driver() {
    var conn net.Conn
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to initialize Connection, trying to reconnect:", err.Error())
        conn = tcpReconnect()
    }

    for {
        _, err = conn.Write([]byte("11|5546|STATUS" + "\r\n"))
        if err != nil {
            println("Write to server failed:", err.Error())
            println("Trying reset the connection...")
            conn = tcpReconnect()
        }

        var replyBuffer = make([]byte, 256)
        _, err = conn.Read(replyBuffer)
        if err != nil {
            println("Read from server failed:", err.Error())
            println("Trying reset the connection...")
            conn = tcpReConnect()
        }

        var reply string
        for i, val := range replyBuffer {
            if val == 13 { //13 is CR and marks the end of the message
                reply = string(replyBuffer[:i])
                break
            }
        }

        fmt.Printf("reply from server=%s\n", reply)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(pollTime))
    }
}
```

Comment: `or will it fill up the RAM?` Yes. Use a loop.

Comment: Yup,  add a loop to driver.  Break out of the inner loop to reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Credits go to @tkausl and @ThunderCat

```
func Driver() {
    for {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to connect:", err.Error())
            fmt.Println("Trying reset the connection...")
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(2000))
        } else {
            for {

                _, err = conn.Write([]byte("11|5546|STATUS" + "\r\n"))
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Write to server failed:", err.Error())
                    fmt.Println("Trying reset the connection...")
                    break
                }

                var replyBuffer = make([]byte, 256)
                _, err = conn.Read(replyBuffer)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Read from server failed:", err.Error())
                    fmt.Println("Trying reset the connection...")
                    break
                }

                var reply string
                for i, val := range replyBuffer {
                    if val == 13 { //13 is CR and marks the end of the message
                        reply = string(replyBuffer[:i])
                        break
                    }
                }

                fmt.Printf("reply from server=_%s_\n", reply)
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(pollTime))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you're probably dealing with transient errors, you might be interested in researching about exponential backoff and circuit breakers to avoid overloading the underlying system. You might also want to set a timeout using https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialTimeout, otherwise a failure in the service you're connecting to might cause your program to hang forever, as the default is no timeout

Comment: Thank you for mentioning these points. I'll definitely implement some of this logic. https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-retry-pattern-with-exponential-back